# Compare values previous date and second previous date in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I'm new to PowerPivot and `DAX`. I've followed some on-line tutorials. Now I have a small problem that I can't solve. I have the following data:

`Date        Instrument Value
 2016-07-27  A          100
 2016-07-27  B          98
 2016-07-26  A          102
 2016-07-25  B          99`

For each date I would like to calculate the difference (Profit/Loss) in `Value` between most recent date and second most recent date. For the data above it would be the following:

`Date        Instrument Value   Profit/Loss
 2016-07-27  A          102     2 ([Val. inst. A 2016-07-27]-[Val. inst. A 2016-07-26])
 2016-07-27  B          98      -1 ([Val. inst. B 2016-07-27]-[Val. inst. B 2016-07-25])
 2016-07-26  A          100
 2016-07-25  B          99`

I have tried with `DAX` to find the second largest date using `=EARLIER([Date])`but haven't managed to get it to work. With the second largest date I would maybe be able to find the `Value` corresponding to that date. Any suggestions how this could be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I came up with a solution  in three steps (the steps can be combined into one step). First I rank all the dates, with the most recent being `1` and the second most recent being `2`. After that I retrieve the `Value` for the second most recent day for each row. Finally I calculate the difference between the `Value`s current row and the `Value` for the second most recent day compared to that row's date.

To rank the dates I used the following:

`=RANKX(FILTER(ALL(table);EARLIER([Instrument])=[Instrument]);[Date];;FALSE())`

Explanation to what I think the `DAX` formula is doing. `RANKX` works by taking a table and then rank the values in a column in that table. Above I've used a filtered table as the table. The filtered table creates a new table for each row containing only the same instrument as the instrument for that particular row. For the first row, the filtered table would look like below.

`Date        Instrument Value
 2016-07-27  A          100
 2016-07-26  A          102`

The dates in that filtered table is then ranked.

`Date        Instrument Value Rank
 2016-07-27  A          100   1
 2016-07-26  A          102   2`

Using the Rank I then pull out the second most recent dates `Value` for each row based on the current row's `Rank-1`.

`Value second most recent date = CALCULATE(MAX([Value]);FILTER(table;EARLIER([Instrument])=[Instrument] && [Date Rank]= EARLIER([Date Rank]))`

Finally I calculate the difference:

`PnL = [Value] - [Value second most recent date]`

I'm not sure what `EARLIER` is doing but I think it is some sort of iterative process.